# Is there a Spanish version of the saying "a New York minute"?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, solicitud-de-modismo

I came across the following expression the other day:

> **[New York Minute](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=New%20York%20Minute)**
>
> A New York minute is an instant. Or as Johnny Carson once said, it's the interval between a Manhattan traffic light turning green and the guy behind you honking his horn.
>
> It appears to have originated in Texas around 1967. It is a reference to the frenzied and hectic pace of New Yorkers' lives. A New Yorker does in an instant what a Texan would take a minute to do.
> *I'll have that ready for you in a New York minute*.

I found this saying really amusing. It is true that people in big cities seem to always be in a hurry, and the above definition made me think of cities like Madrid, for example.

Sure, we could translate "New York minute" as just *instante* or *momento*. But, **does Spanish have any saying with similar connotations to those of "New York minute" to express a very brief moment?**

Comment: It seems to have been used from 1954, says [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/New%20York%20minute).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hay infinidad de expresiones así en español, como:

- En un [pispás](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TDHBi37).
- En un [santiamén](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XFlsFDX).
- En [menos que canta un gallo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ImORZs4#AmzQxCO).
- En [un abrir y cerrar de ojos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QyF9sGX#8CaqdXS).
- En [un decir Jesús](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MRGvkek#81uY8zD).

A partir de aquí tenemos composiciones poéticas, como:

- En lo que dura un parpadeo.
- En lo que dura un caramelo en la puerta de un colegio.
- En lo que dura una morcilla en la barra de un batzoki (caso real encontrado en el CREA).

O la muy reciente:

- En cero coma.

Sin embargo, entiendo que buscas alguna expresión moderna, o que haga referencia a la vida moderna, de ciudad, de caos y desenfreno. No se me ocurre ninguna popularizada, pero estoy seguro de que se puede crear alguna composición similar a las expresadas anteriormente, como por ejemplo:

- En lo que tarda un taxista en bajar la [bandera](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4x4P080#RSSzuQg).

Comment: Todas las expresiones listadas al principio las entendía como modernas, ya que las uso en mi día a día. Me ha decepcionado saber que no hablo *en la onda* del lenguaje actual.

Answer (score -2):

Un "minuto neoyorquino": Nos han servido el café en un minuto neoyorquino!!

Un "minuto de Nueva York": Apúrate, te dije en un minuto, pero de Nueva York!!

La expresión es netamente regional y es válido expresarla tal como es. También necesita contexto cómo otras frases que indican un "instante".

Comment: mmm.... ¿dónde usan esa frase así? Aquí en Colombia sonaría demasiado extraña y no creo que nadie la entienda.

Comment: Igual que "un pispás", necesitas vivir donde esa frase es usada. "La expresión es netamente regional y necesita contexto". Contestando tu pregunta: en Nueva York (y en EUA en general, hay mucha gente que habla español)